# How to skip some symbol characters, when this character is used as a split column symbol in pandas split function

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, split

I have a dataframe like below:
[Original data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DKg3g.png)

```
index   string
0        a,b,c,d,e,f
1        a,b,c,d,e,f
2        a,(I,j,k),c,d,e,f
```

I want to be:
[To be data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fv0Al.png)

```
index   col1    col2    col3    col4    col5    col6
0        a       b       c       d       e        f
1        a       b       c       d       e        f
2        a     (I,j,k)   c       d       e        f
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can split on commas that are not inside brackets. Then convert the result to a DataFrame and assign to `df` columns:

```
df[['col {}'.format(i) for i in range(1,7)]] =  df['string'].str.split(r",\s*(?![^()]*\))").apply(pd.Series)
```

Output:

```
   index             string col 1    col 2 col 3 col 4 col 5 col 6
0      0        a,b,c,d,e,f     a        b     c     d     e     f
1      1        a,b,c,d,e,f     a        b     c     d     e     f
2      2  a,(I,j,k),c,d,e,f     a  (I,j,k)     c     d     e     f
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this :

```
df = df['string'].str.split(r",\s*(?![^()]*\))", expand= True)
df.columns = ['col1','col2','col3','col4','col5','col6']
```